# Call an external .js file javascript function without a long parameter list

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have two MVC Razor views (.cshtml) that have a virtually identical Javascript function within them.

In order to de-duplicate my javascript code I want to extract the Javascript from the views to a single external Javascript file (.js) containing the function (with a parameter that can be used to differentiate the minor differences need for each view).

The Javascript in the views contains Razor syntax to access many asp.net resource file (.resx) text values (e.g. var foo = '@ResourceFileName.Bar';) which the Razor engine unfortunately does not parse for me.

To overcome this I could pass all the resource file text values to the function in the .js file as parameters – but I prefer not to do that as the parameter list would become very large.

The RazorJS package (http://www.nuget.org/packages/RazorJS) will allow me to use Razor syntax within a .js file but this package was last published way back in 2011, which worries me.

What techniques could I use to call the externalised function without a huge  long parameter list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What techniques could I use to call the externalised function without
>   a huge long parameter list ?

It doesn't need to be a huge parameter list. A single parameter containing all the necessary resource properties will be enough:

```
<script>
    var args = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(new 
    {
        foo = ResourceFileName.Foo,
        bar = ResourceFileName.Bar,
        baz = ResourceFileName.Baz
    }));
    myFunction(args);
</script>
```

and then in your function you can access all those properties:

```
function myFunction(args) {
    // you can use args.foo, args.bar and args.baz here
}
```